# "cannot read property 'length' of null" of RegEx result

Tags: javascript, regex

I don`t understand why I get an error after I try to execute this simple JS code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script>
    var str = "x*1/2";
    var patt1 = /( * | \/)/g;
    var result = str.match(patt1);
    document.write(result.length);
</script>
</html>
```

I have tried `typeof` to see the type of my variables:
`str=string; patt1=object; result=object;` but I still have no clue what`s` the problem.

Comment: Because `match` returns `null` if nothing is matched.

Comment: Your regex pattern is invalid as well.

Comment: @AdamAzad: It's valid. It's looking for zero or more spaces, or a space followed by a slash. (Which isn't what the OP wanted, I'm sure, but...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I assume OP wants to do mathematics, and `*` should be escaped? Correct me if I am wrong, please.

Comment: @AdamAzad: That's not what "invalid" means, is all. As I said, it doesn't do what the OP wants, but it's *valid*. It's properly-formed.

Comment: @ s.dragos: It's not clear what you want to match. If you want to match and capture `*` or `/` (literally), then `/([*\/])/`g.

Comment: @s.dragos: Look up a tutorial on regular expressions. Here is the [reference from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: Just a wild guess, but maybe the RegEx result is `null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don`t understand why I get an error after I try to execute this
>   simple JS code

This is happening, because your pattern cannot be matched for the provided input `"x*1/2"`. So `match` returns `null`. Consider the following snippet, where we use a meaningless pattern, which however can be matched for this input.

```js
var str = "x*1/2";
var patt1 = /([*]?\/)/g;
var result = str.match(patt1);
console.log(result.length);
```

Comment: You could have guided OP not to use `document.write` :)

Comment: @AdamAzad `document.write` is used here to only so the result. I am not an advocate of using this method: )

Comment: following your code  i found the right regex for my case :  `patt1 = /([\/]|[*])/g;` now it is ok. thanks Christos.

Comment: @Christos `[\/]` is exactly equivalent to `\/`. The surrounding parentheses are redundant. `[*]` could just as easily be rewritten as `\*`.